# can't figure out this kind of type in C++ (array of struct?)

Tags: c++, struct

If I have a struct like this

```
struct my_struct
{
    float a, b;
};
```

Is there a way to declare an object by doing so?

```
my_struct[10][10] my_struct_inst;
```

If this is allowed, could anyone teach me how to understand this?
Or what's the concept of this code?

So many thanks in advance.

Comment: What resource are you using to learn C++? What does it say about array declarations and their syntax?

Comment: And you can have an array of any type, including other arrays. So an array of arrays (or `my_struct`) is perfectly fine and value. Though I would rather recommend `std::array` for arrays with a size that is known and fixed at compile-time.

Comment: "array of struct?" yes. What makes you doubt that this is an (2d) array of structs?

Comment: The correct syntax is `my_struct my_struct_inst[10][10];`, which any introduction to C++ arrays would tell you. I think you need one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: umm  thanks to all of you, I just want to know if this syntax is reasonable or not. Thanks for the answer and the guy who downvoted it

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is simply wrong. Array size goes after the variable name, not the type:

```
my_struct my_struct_inst[10][10];
```

Note that the *type* of `my_struct_inst` is still `my_struct[10][10]`, that's just the syntax for variable definitions.

---

With modern C++, I would consider using `std::array` instead, though that's not pretty either:

```
std::array< std:array<my_struct, 10>, 10> my_struct_inst;
```

This is basically same thing and equally efficient, but it also offers a bunch of nice methods, which may be useful.

---

To make that easier, you can define it as a type:

```
using my_struct_10x10 = std::array< std:array<my_struct, 10>, 10>;
my_struct_10x10 my_struct_inst;
```

Comment: Thanks, as a freshman of c++, I just want make sure that my understanding is correct